# TreeSet how to corectly display data using iterator

Tags: java

I'm learning about TreeSet and using this collection but I hava a little problem with using iterator... I can't display data ...
And i have second question.. How can i influance at compare my data? ex: now in my class i compare names field (imie) but in case surname i would like to compare surnames (nazwisko). How can i do this?
I will be grateful for your answer!
PS: Sorry for my eng.
This is my code:

```
static String nazwisko, imie;
static int idpracownika, pensja;
static void run(){
    TreeSet<Pracownicy>  list = new TreeSet<Pracownicy>();
    Iterator<Pracownicy> iterator = list.iterator();

    while(true){
        String opcja = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Podaj: Nazwisko, Imiê, idPracownika, Pensjê");
        //StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(opcja);
        switch(opcja){
        case ("exit"):
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        case("name"):
            System.out.println("Imiona:");
            //while (iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(list);
            break;
        case("surname"):
            System.out.println("Nazwiska:");
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(iterator.next().getName());  
            }
            break;

        default:


            String[] bufor;
            bufor = opcja.split(" ");
            imie = bufor[0];
            nazwisko = bufor[1];
            idpracownika = Integer.parseInt(bufor[2]);
            pensja = Integer.parseInt(bufor[3]); 

            list.add(new Pracownicy(nazwisko, imie, idpracownika, pensja));
        break;  
        }
        }



public class Pracownicy implements Comparable<Pracownicy> {

    public String nazwisko;
    public String imie;
    public int idPracownika;
    public int pensja;


    Pracownicy(String nazwisko, String imie, int idPracownika, int pensja){
        this.nazwisko=nazwisko;
        this.imie=imie;
        this.idPracownika=idPracownika;
        this.pensja=pensja;
    }

    public String getName()     {   return imie; }
    public String getSurname()  {   return nazwisko; }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pracownicy o) {    
        return this.imie.compareTo(o.imie);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return nazwisko + " " + imie + " " + idPracownika + " " + pensja + "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to compare surnames

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Pracownicy o) {    
    int firstNameEqual = this.imie.compareTo(o.imie);
    // if first name is equal then compare on surname
    if(firstNameEqual==0){
         return this.nazwisko.compareTo(o.nazwisko);
    }else{
         return firstNameEqual;
    }
}
```

---

You can create different `Comparator` to sort as per your requirement. Finally use `Collections.sort()` to sort a `List`.

Sample code:

```
TreeSet<Pracownicy> set = new TreeSet<Pracownicy>();

Comparator<Pracownicy> surnameComparator = new Comparator<Pracownicy>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Pracownicy o1, Pracownicy o2) {
        return o1.nazwisko.compareTo(o2.nazwisko);
    }
};

Comparator<Pracownicy> firstNameComparator = new Comparator<Pracownicy>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Pracownicy o1, Pracownicy o2) {
        return o1.imie.compareTo(o2.imie);
    }
};

List<Pracownicy> list = new ArrayList<Pracownicy>(set);

// sort by surname
Collections.sort(list, surnameComparator);

// sort by first name
Collections.sort(list, firstNameComparator);
```

---

How to iterate the `Set`?

```
Iterator<Pracownicy> iterator = set.iterator();
Pracownicy pracownicy = null;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    pracownicy = iterator.next();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, but i would like in case compare only names(imie) and in in case surname compare only surnames(nazwisko) if it's posible of course...
Do you know how to display my treeset using iterator?

Comment: you are doing correct. Where is the issue? what are the inputs?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answers and time!
This is my whole code: http://pastebin.com/tPqkUtgy
What I do wrong?
I know that i shouldn't paste link to pastebin but whole code is to long.... 

I will be grateful for your answer!

Comment: I have little question because i tested it with ArrayLists -> ex. i input a a 1 1 and b a 1 1 and for name i recive a a and for surname b a but i want to get: name: A and surname A, B... sow how should i do this?

Comment: Ok i made it. First Insert all dato in to ArrayList and next into treeset using comparator